# TinyMCE Popup Window in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I am creating wordpress plugin where registering a TinyMCE button for inserting shortcode with a popup window `pop_up_window.php` for setting. But inside the `pop_up_window.php` page, I can't dynamic to links those will work when Wordpress is installed in a root directory or in a sub directory.

Screenshot: [image]

i tried, `../../../`, `../../../../` but no luck.

I would like to know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: If you're creating a Wordpress Plugin, then you should probably be taking advantage of `wp_enqueue_script()` and using `add_action('wp_head', 'script_enqueue_func');` Since `TinyMCE` is registered previously by WP, you don't even need to know the path. This is all given that you're actually developing a Plugin the Proper way.

Comment: I found a solution here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/show-dialog-box-in-tinymce-plugin-and-use-wordpress-php-functions-in-it

That works fine for me.